# How to add integer value in sql select query?

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a project where my sql query is

```
SELECT Name 
FROM techer_reg 
LIMIT 3
```

**How can I add an integer value instead of 3?**

In the sense, this select query should be look like:

```
SELECT Name 
FROM techer_reg 
LIMIT (My integer value)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using a parameter:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnect))
{
con.Open();
int myLimit = 4;
using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT Name FROM techer_reg LIMIT @LM", con))
    {
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LM", myLimit);
    using (SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader())
        {
        while (reader.Read())
            {
            int id = (int)reader["iD"];
            string desc = (string)reader["description"];
            Console.WriteLine("ID: {0}\n    {1}", iD, desc);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

procedure:

```
DELIMITER $

create PROCEDURE getData(limit INT)
begin
   SET @limit= limit;
   PREPARE exec_statment FROM "SELECT Name FROM techer_reg LIMIT limit ?;";
   EXECUTE exec_statment USING @limit;
   DEALLOCATE PREPARE exec_statment;
end$

DELIMITER ;
```

and call it using

```
call getData(3)
```